# How to convert CHAT to TextGrid in a batch?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, praat, spoken-language, welsh

[Siarad](http://bangortalk.org.uk/speakers.php?c=siarad) corpus is a corpus of spoken Welsh (~40 hours, all transcribed, glossed and translated!). I want to analyze some conversations using [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/). Praat uses the TextGrid format, but the Siarad corpus has CHAT files, so I need to convert these to TextGrid.

I tried [CLAN](http://dali.talkbank.org/clan/)’s `chat2textgrid` but for some reason it outputs only the metadata. Am I not using it correctly? Does it work for you? I tried the Linux version (UnixCLAN).

I did manage to convert individual files manually by importing the CHAT files into [ELAN](https://tla.mpi.nl/tools/tla-tools/elan/) and exporting TextGrid files. It is OK for my needs, but I’m sure there is a way to do this automatically in a batch.